# Problem with str.partition() and tuple unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I am using `partition` in strings and am trying to use `tuple` unpacking on them but it's returning the error `expected 3 got 1`. So here's my code. Please explain where I went wrong.

```
a='aca'
for a,b,c in a.partition('c'):
print(a)
```

Comment: I think you mean `a, b, c = a.partition('c')`?

Comment: you do not want to use a for loop for that. just do `a, b, c = a.partition('c')`

Comment: don't use `a` both in the variable and in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable twice (`a`) and no need to use a loop
just write `a,b,c = String_name.partition('c')`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a for loop for this, tuple unpacking is listed under the [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) section in the official Python documentation.

```
In [11]: A = 'aca'

In [12]: a, b, c = A.partition('c')

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 'a'

In [14]: b
Out[14]: 'c'

In [15]: c
Out[15]: 'a'
```